# Find $\int \left(e^{\frac{x}{2}}-\frac{5}{x^2}\right)dx$ by substituion

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$\int \left(e^{\frac{x}{2}}-\frac{5}{x^2}\right)dx$

I am supposed to use u substitution, but I'm not sure which variable to choose as u.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If forced, I'd use $u=\frac x 2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** You have

$$
\int e^{ax} dx=\frac 1 a e^{ax}+C, \quad a \neq 0,
$$ and
$$
\int \frac 1 {x^2} dx=-\frac 1 x+C
$$ then use linearity of the integral.

Comment: Oh, I understand now! So I would end up with (2e^(t/2))-(5/t)+C

Comment: @Manuel Rather: $$2e^{x/2}+\frac 5 x+C$$ Thanks.